# Problema con Android 6.0.1 (Java-Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema para iniciar mi aplicacion en dispositivos con Android 6.0.1, no se si sera algun tema de compatibilidad o algo por el estilo, en dispositivos con versiones mas nuevas de android me anda ecxelente...

Dejo lo que me arroja cuando ejecuto mi app en modo Debug

Y mas abajo actualizo con la funcion guarda_datos_db()

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vendedoresbingo, PID: 5481
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vendedoresbingo/com.example.vendedoresbingo.app.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
        at com.example.vendedoresbingo.app.MainActivity.guarda_datos_db(MainActivity.java:231)
        at com.example.vendedoresbingo.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 




//Guarda los datos extraidos de la BD
    private void guarda_datos_db(){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(MainActivity.this, "bd usuarios", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase baseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        id_usuario = 1;

        Cursor fila = baseDeDatos.rawQuery("select desde, hasta from usuarios where id=' "+id_usuario+" ' ", null);
        fila.moveToFirst();
        desde = fila.getInt(0);
        hasta = fila.getInt(1);
        baseDeDatos.close();
        fila.close();
    }
```

Comment: Cual es el código que estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando funciones basicas en casi todas mis clases. tambien en algunas estoy usando una base de datos SQLite y estoy haciendo uso de JavaMail

Comment: Chequea que hace en la linea que da error: `MainActivity.guarda_datos_db()`(MainActivity.java linea 231). Al parecer hay algun problema con acceso a datos. Si compartes el codigo de guarda_datos_db() puede ser mas facil saber que pasa

Comment: Ahi actualizo mi pregunta con la funcion guarda_datos_db()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu consulta no obtiene datos y tu estas intentando leer información que no existe, por esa razón obtienes el error:

> Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0
> requested, with a size of 0

Debes realizar la lectura de los datos de esta forma, asegurando solo leer si existe información en el cursor:

```
  Cursor fila = baseDeDatos.rawQuery("select desde, hasta from usuarios where id=' "+id_usuario+" ' ", null);
  if(fila.moveToFirst()){
     desde = fila.getInt(0);
     hasta = fila.getInt(1);
  }
```

tu código sería:

```
//Guarda los datos extraidos de la BD
private void guarda_datos_db(){
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(MainActivity.this, "bd usuarios", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase baseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    id_usuario = 1;

    Cursor fila = baseDeDatos.rawQuery("select desde, hasta from usuarios where id=' "+id_usuario+" ' ", null);
    if(fila.moveToFirst()){
      desde = fila.getInt(0);
      hasta = fila.getInt(1);
    }
    baseDeDatos.close();
    fila.close();
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco por tu ayuda, la verdad que muy buena respuesta, hasta el codigo me diste ya resuelto, gracias...